# Issues with matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I am trying to show a matrix and a related vector data together using matplotlib matshow.

```
vec_data = np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

mat_data = np.array([
       [ 0. ,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0.1],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0. ]])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(4,4),sharey=False,sharex=True,gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[25,1]})
axes[0].matshow(mat_data)
axes[1].matshow(vec_data)
axes[1].tick_params(direction='out', length=6, width=0)
axes[1].set_yticklabels([''])
axes[1].set_xlabel('vector')
```

The resulting image would be as follows:

[image]

The issue here is that when putting these two matshow images together mess up the ylim of the first image: it is supposed to show the values from 0 to 9, but it only shows a range 0.5 to 8.5. If I plot the image alone with the command

```
plt.matshow(mat_data)
```

I get the desired image with correct ylim.

[image]

Anybody knows what causes the issue and how I can fix it? I tried to use

```
axes[0].set_ylim([-0.5,9.5])
```

but it does not work.

P.S.: I have used the keyword gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[25,1]} so that the vector is shown as a vector--otherwise it will be shown as a matrix with blank values like the following.

[image]

The argument sharex = True is used for plt.subplots in order for the vector and the matrix to be aligned. Without the argument, the graph will be like the following

[image]

but note there that the issue with the ylim is gone--so it is possible that the argument is the main cause of this issue. I guess if I can find another way to align the two images without using "sharex = True" can solve this issue.

Comment: Why do you use `sharex=True`? What happens if you leave that out?

Comment: I use it to align the vector and the matrix... as explained in the edited question.

Comment: What if you do `for ax in axes: ax.set_aspect('auto')`? The images will be squeezed in y-direction, but you'll be able to see the entire image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sharex=True` for the subplots overconstrains the system. Matplotlib will hence free the plot limits to be able to show the plot with the given specifications.

The solution would be to use `sharex=False` (the default). Then the height-ratios need to match the dimensions of the images, i.e.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(4,4),sharey=False,sharex=False,
                    gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[mat_data.shape[0],vec_data.shape[0]]})
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vec_data = np.array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
mat_data = np.random.choice([0,.1,.5,1], size=(10,10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(4,4),sharey=False,sharex=False,
                    gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[mat_data.shape[0],vec_data.shape[0]]})
axes[0].matshow(mat_data)
axes[1].matshow(vec_data)
axes[1].tick_params(direction='out', length=6, width=0)
axes[1].set_yticklabels([''])
axes[1].set_xlabel('vector')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution -- works like a charm!