# Combining different imshow and bar in subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wrote a function to plot some class predictions for images. I can't seem to figure out how to visualize everything properly. I have two specific problems: 1) I can't get the aspect ratio right for the barplot (bottom row), and 2) I can't get the tick marks for the bottom row to rotate for **all** plots instead of just the last one (but the same seems to go for the aspect ratio question). First row - the images themselves - seem to plot just fine.

```
def plot_classifier_predictions(classifier: Sequential, model_name: str, compression_factor: float, x: np.ndarray, y_true: np.ndarray,
                             examples=5, random=True, save=True, plot=True):


    # Make predictions
    y_pred = classifier.predict(x=x)

    # Set indices
    indices = rnd.sample(range(len(x)), examples) if random else [i for i in range(examples)]

    # Get image dimension
    image_dim = x.shape[1]

    # Plot parameters
    plot_count = examples * 2
    row_count = 2
    col_count = int(ceil(plot_count / row_count))

    # Initialize axes
    fig, subplot_axes = plt.subplots(row_count,
                                     col_count,
                                     squeeze=True,
                                     figsize=(16, 10),
                                     constrained_layout=True)

    # Set colors
    colors = sns.color_palette('pastel', n_colors=len(dat.CLASSES))

    # Fill axes
    for i in range(plot_count):

        row = i // col_count
        col = i % col_count

        original_image = x[indices[col]]

        ax = subplot_axes[row][col]

        # First row: show original images
        if row == 0:
            ax.set_title("Image")
            ax.imshow(original_image)
            ax.axis('off')

        # Second row: show predictions
        else:
            ax.set_title("Predictions")

            ax.bar(x=range(len(dat.CLASSES)), height=y_pred[indices[col]], color=colors)
            ax.set_xticks(ticks=range(len(dat.CLASSES)))
            ax.set_xticklabels(dat.CLASSES)
            ax.set_aspect(2)
            plt.xticks(rotation=45)
            plt.ylim(0,1.0)



    # General make-up
    plt.tight_layout()

    # Title
    plt.suptitle(
        "Predictions (image dim {} - compression {})".format(image_dim, compression_factor),
        fontweight='bold')
```

This is the current result:

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_ylim(0,1)` instead of `plt.ylim()`. And `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)` instead of `plt.xticks`.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how set the height of the subplots (so not the ylim)? My barplots take up significantly more height. I know how to set the overall figsize, but not for individual subplots.

Comment: `aspect` is not a good way to set the height of the plots. Instead one could use the `gridspec_kw` argument of `subplots` to set a useful `height_ratio` (like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48542521/4124317), though for a different purpose).

Comment: Or maybe rather [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53047241/4124317)